# Typecasting in Visual C++ DLL Programming

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, command-line-interface, typecasting-operator

I have a code in Visual C++ , I have a data in the data type **array  ^** & I want to convert this data in some other format like UBYTE* but when i am doing Typecasting that time Visual Studio will display one ERROR:
 **convert from 'cli::array ^' to UBYTE***  

Please tell me how to resolve this problem:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use marshalling, something like this:

```
array<Byte>^ managed_array = ...;
unsigned char *unmanaged_array =
                (unsigned char*)malloc(managed_array->Length); 

Marshal::Copy(        unmanaged_array,
                                    0,
              IntPtr(unmanaged_array),
                managed_array->Length);

...

free(unmanaged_array);
```

Note: unmanaged_array's data is copy of managed_array's data.